# Build a debian without bazaar

Tags: packaging, deb

I have an app that is already built into binary. I want to distribute it via my website. I find it difficult to build as [Ubuntu Packaging](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/singlehtml/) guide have changed a lot since I checked last time. Am not sure of this but it seems I need bazaar to successful build it.

I want a deb file that will simply install binary and related libraries and resources to where I want. Should user want to uninstall, then it simply delete the files and that is it. Something like InnoSetup or NSIS for windows.
Last time I built using [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20141210051522/http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/), but it does not work any longer. Is it possible to build a deb file simply and without bazaar?

Comment: »»Should user want to uninstall, then it simply delete the files«« : That's what is done with `sudo apt-get remove [package-name]` .... A package can be built from your files with `dpkg-deb -b packagename packagename_version_architecture.deb` ... a control file with ~8 lines is required.

Comment: Can you post a link which documents control file format and may be example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up Using [debreate](https://antumdeluge.github.io/debreate-web/) It provided what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Building a package.deb from directories :

```
cd new-folder/ && mkdir -p  packagename/DEBIAN
```

Your files e.g. `usr/local/bin/executable` goes into `packagename/` ... and the file `control` into `DEBIAN/`

Example control file :

```
Package: name
Version: 1.1-1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: amd64
Depends:
Maintainer: Jerry Donut <jerry@donut.com>
Description:
```

The architecture choices are typically : i386, amd64, noarch

Then you can try :

```
cd new-folder/
dpkg-deb -b packagename packagename_version_architecture.deb
```

Then unpack the package.deb to check if it's OK. Else, do some adjustments and repeat the `dpkg-deb -b` command.

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo, so did it work for u ?

Comment: Nope. See my answer